# ADF SSO with Active Directory

Tags: single-sign-on, oracle-adf

If SSO was to be implemented on a ADF application with Active Directory, will we get the securityContext object with all the user roles from the active directory? I have an ADF application implementation that uses ActiveDirectoryAuthentication and was able to use the securityContext object to manipulate various controls on the page but now I have been asked to look into the SSO. I am not pretty sure how to handle controls in a page if SSO is implemented.
Open to suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing ADF specific when enabling SSO on Weblogic: this procedure is the same for any java web application.

This requires a good amount of DevOps configuration, you can check this blog:

http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/single-sign-on-with-windows-kerberos-on.html

Bottom line, this is more a DevOps task, rather than programmer's or Weblogic Administrator's.

Comment: I went through that blog, but what I am confused about is since the application will be using the weblogic user configured on AD server how will I get the user specific roles?

Comment: SSO is just a replacement of Login screen. Everything else remains the same: WLS will use the ADAuthenticator to load the roles.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I'll try this out and come back with the result